# Form submit handler does not use changed values of state variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning React by writing out a basic CRUD app. A pretty straight forward process for many. When I'm implementing the Edit functionality of the app, I'm facing an issue with the data that gets submitted by the edit button.

My code is as belows -

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Edit({elementList, setElementList, editElement}) {
    const [fieldA, setFieldA] = useState(editElement.field_a)
    const [fieldB, setFieldB] = useState(editElement.field_b)
    const [fieldC, setFieldC] = useState(editElement.field_c)

    async function submitHandler(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(fieldA)
        console.log(fieldB)
        console.log(fieldC)
        // do stuff with API
        // update elementList using setElementList
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler} id="edit-form">
            <input type="text" value={fieldA} onChange={(event) => {setFieldA(event.target.value)}}></input>
            <input type="text" value={fieldB} onChange={(event) => {setFieldB(event.target.value)}}></input>
            <input type="text" value={fieldC} onChange={(event) => {setFieldC(event.target.value)}}></input>
            <button form="edit-form" type="submit">Edit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

I'm initializing the component with values of the `editElement` state variable which is passed from the parent component which has the list of all elements. Whenever the user clicks on the edit button next to the element name, it sets the `editElement` to that particular element and triggers a navigation to the Edit page. On a successful Edit, the user is re-navigated to the parent component and the `editElement` is set to `null`.

When I edit the values of each `input`, I know there is a change in the state variable because a) I can see the value changing in the input box and b) I'm logging the values of all the state variables on every render using an `useEffect` hook.

However, when I try to click on the button and submit the form, the `submitHandler` function takes the default values i.e. the values on component load and not the changed values. For example, if `field_a` is changed to 23 from 11, the `console.log(fieldA)` *inside* the `submitHandler` logs 11 and NOT 23 even though 23 is rendered in the input box.

This happens regardless of if the state variable is initialized with any non-null value. A `const [fieldD, setFieldD] = useState('')` will also log an empty string whatever the value in the input box.

I've looked across pretty much everywhere and spent the better part of a day trying to understand why this is happening. I found a couple of blogs and tutorials and even answers on StackOverflow that mention that the state change might not have happened yet. But this isn't the issue as I have mentioned since I've logged each component render and the value has been changed.

I've even tried to pass a `useRef` to `editElement` instead of passing the state variable in case it was resetting the component somehow. However, the problem persisted and even occurred for those state variables which are not initialized with values from the `editElement` state variable.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me figure out where I'm screwing up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your handler in a `useCallback` hook that also accepts an array of dependencies so that you know it will be updated based on that.

You can refactor your code like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Edit({elementList, setElementList, editElement}) {
    const [fieldA, setFieldA] = useState(editElement.field_a)
    const [fieldB, setFieldB] = useState(editElement.field_b)
    const [fieldC, setFieldC] = useState(editElement.field_c)

    const submitHandler = useCallback(async event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(fieldA)
        console.log(fieldB)
        console.log(fieldC)
        // do stuff with API
        // update elementList using setElementList
    }, [fieldA, fieldB, fieldC])

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler} id="edit-form">
            <input type="text" value={fieldA} onChange={(event) => {setFieldA(event.target.value)}}></input>
            <input type="text" value={fieldB} onChange={(event) => {setFieldB(event.target.value)}}></input>
            <input type="text" value={fieldC} onChange={(event) => {setFieldC(event.target.value)}}></input>
            <button form="edit-form" type="submit">Edit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

This can be useful also if you add states that don't necessary need to update the submit handler in order to prevent unnecessary updates

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this didn't help, sorry.
I still can't figure out _why_ it's happening.